# Google Map call not working

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-maps

So, I'm a little confused. I tried calling a google map with the api and tutorial provided here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map

But I seem to be unable to get it to work correctly, and my map div always ends up being a grey box.
Here's the html and js that I used. Please let me know if there is some sort of glaring error, or if I should be using another api...

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>

...

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
</script>
```

my css is set to have the height and width be 300px and 500px respectively... if that matters to you personally.

Comment: The code to initialize the map in [that tuturial](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map) is not the same as your posted code `var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas'); var mapOptions = {center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403,-78.5463), 
zoom: 8, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
 var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);`

Answer (score 0):

I think your code doesn't use the options. I'm not sure that's THE problem, but that's A problem:

try:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, mapOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for your map to appear, start with this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:300;height:500">
<script>
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var mapOpts = { mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, zoom: 2, center: new google.maps.LatLng(20, 0) };

var map_canvas = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is the `mapOptions` is not included when the map is initialized.

it's supposed to be like this:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, mapOptions);
```

~ try to read again the tutorial provided, it's defined that the 'center', 'zoom level', and 'map type' are required options.

> *Options for the map, such as the center, zoom level, and the map type.
>   There are many more options that can be set, but these three are **required**.*